# Inner text of non float div is positioned regarding to previous float div

Tags: html, css, css-float

My questions is why in following html/css code "Green" text is outside green box. Is is positioned horizontally as it should inside green box, but vertically it is below red box. And why blue box is vertically positioned below green box, not below red one:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="red">Red</div>
<div class="green">Green</div>
<div class="blue">Blue</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  color: red;
}

.green {
  width: 18%;
  height: 40px;
  border-color: green;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}

.blue {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  color: blue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3tk7Lwbj/1/

As I understand float description, the red and blue boxes are taken from normal flow, so green box should be ignored why counting their position.

Comment: add `clear: left` for class `.green` as the `float` of the previous div is affecting its behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Solution given by @vivekkupadhyay is correct one. When you apply float property of css to any block level element then it gets float on the screen without taking space on the page. So any element added in between or after the floated elements, it gets add behind them.

Now, about clear property. What it does. If you add property clear:both, then both sides (left/right) of that element gets clear and it take full available space on page. And if use only clear: left(right as per requirement) it clear space at left side and utilize full space.

In case of .green class, when you added property clear:left then it clear its left side but at this side found element red so it get moved on new line with full size on screen and due to full size taken by .gree, .blue gets add below it.

Hope so I a have added enough details to clear your question.